Java Spring Data JPA postgres incorrect associations, nested response
I am using Java Spring Data JPA for ORM implementation for Postgres database,following is my use case - 
tables are app_user, idcard, role, contact and application.
Where 1 app_user can have only 1 idcard,
1 app_user can have 1 role, but a role can be associated with multiple app_user,
one app_user can have multiple contacts
and multiple app_user can be associated with numerous application, and one application can be related to various app_user.
ERD looks like this -


Entity classes look like -
app_user table -

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private IDCard idCard;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_application",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "application_id")
    )
    private Set<Application> applications = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;
}


idcard table -

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "idcard")
public class IDCard {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "id_number")
    private String idNumber;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}


contact table -
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    private String email;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}

role table -

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}


application table -

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "application")
public class Application {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "applications")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}

When I run the springboot application, I get nested result,seems either the table structuring or the associations are incorrect, what am I doing wrong?


Use @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference:

@JsonManagedReference is used on the parent side of the relationship.
@JsonBackReference is used on the child side to break the recursion.

For example, in your User and IDCard classes:
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private IDCard idCard;

 @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;

Or use @JsonIgnore in IDCard class:
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@JsonIgnore
private User user;


could you explain more by Parent and Child side? The table having the foreign key would be considered Parent?

You can find more here: link,
and how to avoid infinite recursion link
